# not able to list and delete the artifact registry artifacts from gcp via script

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-api-python-client

I am writing one script which is going to delete the artifacts which are older and created before 15 days from current date.

Below is the script:

```
from google.cloud.artifactregistry import ArtifactRegistryClient
from google.cloud.artifactregistry_v1.types import Tag
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Set the project and repository information
project_id = '<my-project-id>'
location = '<region>'
repository_name = '<container-images>'
package_name='<application-name>'

# Initialize the client
client = ArtifactRegistryClient()

# Define the parent resource name
parent = f'projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}/repositories/{repository_name}/packages/{package_name}'
print(parent)

# Calculate the timestamp for 30 days ago
cutoff_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)
print(cutoff_date)

# List the docker images in the repository
tags = client.list_tags(request={"parent": parent})
#print(images)

# Loop through the tags, retrieve additional information, and delete the ones older than 15 days
for tag in tags:
    tag_data = client.get_tag(request={"name": tag.name})
    # Retrieve the create time from the tag data
    create_time = tag_data.create_time
    # Perform the comparison with the cutoff date
    if create_time and create_time.ToDatetime() < cutoff_date:
 #       client.delete_tag(request={"name": tag.name})
        print(f'Deleted tag: {tag.name}')
```

However, while running the above script, I am getting this below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<user-name>/Downloads/remove_unused_artifatcs.py", line 30, in <module>
    create_time = tag_data.create_time
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 758, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Unknown field for Tag: create_time
```

Can someone please help me fix this issue.

I want to remove the image version tags which are older than 15 days from current date.